# The Hölder seminorm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{D, \alpha}: C(\mathbb{R}_0^+, \mathbb{R}^d) \to [0, \infty]$ is meaurable if $D$ is countable

Tags: analysis, continuity, stochastic-processes

I am working through some old notes about stochastic processes. As we know, Hölder continuity plays an important role when studying the Brownian motion.

The definition of $\alpha$-Hölder continuity is as follows:

> Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}_0^+$, $\alpha > 0$. A function $f: \mathbb{R}_0^+ \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is called $\alpha$-Hölder continuous on $D$ if
> $$ \lVert f \rVert_{D,\alpha} := \sup \left\{ \frac{\lvert f(t) - f(s) \rvert}{\lvert t -s\rvert^\alpha} : s,t \in D, s \neq t \right\} < \infty.$$
> In this case, we write $f \in C^\alpha(D)$.

In the lecture notes a few remarks follow, one of which is:

> The map $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{D,\alpha}: C(\mathbb{R}_0^+; \mathbb{R}^d) \to [0, \infty]$ is $\left(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\right)^{\otimes \mathbb{R}_0^+}$-$\mathcal{B}([0, \infty])$-measurable if $D$ is countable.

**Question:** I don't know how to prove this statement. I'm even unsure if it makes sense that way, as $C(\mathbb{R}_0^+; \mathbb{R}^d)$ is not contained in the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)^{\otimes \mathbb{R}_0^+}$. One idea I had was to find some kind of inequality and argue with continuity.

Comment: Do you remember of how the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)^{\otimes \mathbb{R_0^+}}$ (also know as the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra) is defined? That should help you rewrite $\left\| \cdot\right\|$ in terms of something measurable (hint: the countable sup of things that are clearly measurable).

Comment: Thanks, I wrote everything in terms of the projections $\pi_t$ ($t \in D$). However, shouldn't the seminorm be $C(\mathbb{R}_0^+; \mathbb{R}^d) \cap \left((\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\right)^{\otimes \mathbb{R}_0^+}-\mathcal{B}([0, \infty])$-measurable then?

Comment: If $D$ is countable then yes the semi-norm is measurable. Isn't that what you wanted to prove?

Comment: Yes, I am just wondering what $\sigma$-algebra is the right one.

Comment: In fact, the trace $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)^{\otimes \mathbb{R}_0^+}$ on $C\left(\mathbb{R}_0^+, \mathbb{R}^d\right)$ and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for the metric of uniform convergence on compacts are the same.